# I need to map custom component value to record field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, picklist

I am looking for solution using LWC. My problem statement is like:
I have custom component which is showing us roles in picklick and I need to map selected roles into custom field, Can you pls suggest me how to do it? Custom field: UserRoles__c

**Cmp**

```
<lightning-card title="Display User Role" icon-name="custom:custom63">

    <lightning-combobox name="Role" label="Role Name" placeholder="Choose Role" value={value} onchange={handleChange} options={roleOptions}></lightning-combobox>

    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">        

        <lightning-button-group class="slds-m-top_small">      

            <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSave} alignment-bump="right"></lightning-button>

        </lightning-button-group>

    </div>

</lightning-card>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';

import getUserRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getUserRoles';

let i=0;

export default class DisplayUserRole extends LightningElement {

    @track items = []; //this will hold key, value pair

    @track value = ''; //initialize combo box value

    @track chosenValue = '';

    @wire(getUserRoles)

    wiredUserRoles({ error, data }) {

    if (data) {

        //create array with elements which has been retrieved controller

        //here value will be Id and label of combobox will be Name

        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ];

    }

    this.error = undefined;

    } else if (error) {

        this.error = error;

        this.contacts = undefined;

    }

    }
    //getter to return items which is mapped with options attribute

    get roleOptions() {

        return this.items;

    }
    handleChange(event) {

        // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option

        const selectedOption = event.detail.value;

        console.log('selected value=' + selectedOption);

        this.chosenValue = selectedOption;

    }
    //this value will be shown as selected value of combobox item

    get selectedValue(){

    return this.chosenValue;

    }
    handleSave() {

    }
}
```

**Apex:**

```
public with sharing class UserRoleController {

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

    public static List<UserRole> getUserRoles(){

    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole];

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are trying something like the following:

"When the user chooses a role from the picklist and clicks Save, then you want the value from the picklist to be updated in a record custom field called UserRoles__c?"

If this is what you would like to do, you can achieve this using the updateRecord [uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record), you can follow the documentation to achieve the result.

Things to note here, Id is mandatory input for updateRecord, as you need to specify which record to update right.

So, for example, let's say your component, sits on the Contact record page. (**Assumptions**), and user chooses a picklist value from your component and click's save and you want the UserRoles__c field to have the picklist value.

Then the code would look something like this:

JS

```
...//your current imports
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Id'; //Change this too, to get the Id field from the right object, in your case, this should be the object where your UserRoles__c field is.
import USER_ROLES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.UserRoles__c'; //Make sure to change this, to the correct path of where the field is. I am just showing an example here.
export default class DisplayUserRole extends LightningElement {
@api recordId // I am just putting this assuming, you are placing your component on the recordpage where the field UserRoles__c needs to be updated.


handleSave(){
   const fields = {};
   fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId; //change this to the recordId you wish to update.
   fields[USER_ROLES_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.chosenValue;
   let recordInput = {fields};
   updateRecord(recordInput)
   .then(() => console.log('Updated Successfully'))
   .catch(error => console.log('Error updating', error);
 }
}
```

Please make sure to read the comments in the code above to make necessary changes to your code. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I made changes according this, but as you can see at line :
 
this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ]; .
I am getting Id only but I need Name.

Comment: @wire(getUserRoles)
wiredUserRoles({ error, data }) {
if (data) {
    this.roleOptions = data.map(item => ({ label: item, value: item }));
    }
}

you can extract the values this way.